# Using R to create boxplot with 2 variables on X axis

Tags: r, boxplot

I am fairly new to R and want to combine 2 basic box plots into 1.

My code so far is...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vegan)
spiders <- read_csv(file = "Spider Data.csv")
class(spiders)
str(spiders)
boxplot(spiders$Length_mm ~ spiders$Distance)
boxplot(spiders$Length_mm ~ spiders$Cover)
```

Here are the plots I have so far as well as something like what I want to create (ignore the label names in the coloured graph, I just took the picture from google, but I want something similar)

my first boxplot

[image]

my second boxplot

[image]

what I want my graph to look like (ignore labels)

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please consider using reproducible data (e.g., from a dataset like `iris`, rather than a csv file on your computer). [This post has some great info for how to write a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/76-add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/

Answer (score 0):

If you wan tto stay with base R, and not other plot library, you can use `at=` in boxplots to say where the boxes should be displayed and `col=` to set different colors. This would give for example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vegan)
spiders <- read_csv(file = "Spider Data.csv")
class(spiders)
str(spiders)
boxplot(spiders$Length_mm ~ spiders$Distance, at=c(0.85,1.85), col=2, names="Good")
boxplot(spiders$Length_mm ~ spiders$Cover, at=c(1.15,2.15), col=3, names="Bad")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boxplot(spiders$Length_mm ~ spiders$Distance+spiders$Cover)
```

Have a look at [How do I make a boxplot with two categorical variables in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369870/how-do-i-make-a-boxplot-with-two-categorical-variables-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ggplot` library will the `fill` parameter:

```
ggplot(data = spiders, aes = (x = Distance, y = Length_mm, fill = Cover) +
   geom_boxplot()
```

You can see the documentation [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html) and this usefull web site [r-graph-gallery](https://r-graph-gallery.com/boxplot.html).

Hope it's hepl!